# Ajax/C# help retrieving certain data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I have an employee managment site which was created using .Net, entity asp etc.

In the index you can see all the employees, names etc. But when I click on their profile it takes you to another page *Profile/Index* and there theres only details about the clicked employee.

I cant get the name to display from that single click, all I could do is make the first or the last name from the collection to show, not for each of them.

I thought about using ajax to retrieve the names and my code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.get("RSAT.Api/V1/Data/Entities/Employee.", function (Name) {
                alert("Name: " + Name);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In the profile Controller

```
var baseViewModel = base.GetLayoutViewModel();
var viewModel = new HomeViewModel()
{
    User = baseViewModel.User,
    RoleCollection = baseViewModel.RoleCollection,
    TableCollection = baseViewModel.TableCollection,
    Olap = baseViewModel.Olap,
    Localization = baseViewModel.Localization,
    EmployeeCollection = (from userinfo in context.Userinfo
                          where userinfo.Userid == userinfo.UserCode
                          select new Employee()
                          {
                              Name = userinfo.Name,
                           }).ToList()
};
```

And I am not sure how to approach this one, wether to modify html things such as `@Html.DisplayNameFor` ( which didnt work), `@Model.xxxx` only displayed first or last name from the collection and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is in MVC then you can use ViewBag to display the details as shown below. In controller you need to declare and assign viewbag as shown below.

```
var empDetails = dbEClaim.EP_GetEmpInfo_2018(User.Identity.Name).ToList();
if (empDetails.Count >= 1)
{
  ViewBag.EmpName = empDetails[0].EMP_NM;
  ViewBag.CityName = empDetails[0].CM_CITY_NAME;
  ViewBag.Division = empDetails[0].div_nm;               
}
```

In view to access viewbage you need to write as shown below.

```
@ViewBag.EmpName
```

You can also use session as shown below.

```
Session["CompCd"] = empDetails[0].Comp_cd;
```

In view to access session you need to write as shown below.

```
@Session["EmpName"]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: could you give more detail please about the database code u wrote

Comment: I have created a stored procedure and used EF to import it as function as shown above.